# How to encode this from hex to hex in php ? hmac sha-1

Tags: php, encode, sha1, hmac

I need to write THIS in php

https://cryptii.com/pipes/QiZmdA

I have tried those but don't produce the same result

```
<?php
    echo hash_hmac('sha1', '002590cd26da', "8544e3b47eca58f9583043f8");
 echo var_dump(hash_hmac("sha1", "002590cd26da", pack("H*", "8544e3b47eca58f9583043f8")));
?>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need convert the hex string to binary first then use function `hash_hmac` with 'true' parameter to get binary output and last,convert the binary HMAC to a hex string.

Here fixed example code :

```php
<?php
$data = hex2bin("002590cd26da"); // Convert the hex string to binary
$key = hex2bin("8544e3b47eca58f9583043f8"); // Convert the hex key to binary

$hmac = hash_hmac('sha1', $data, $key, true); // Use 'true' to get binary output
$hmac_hex = bin2hex($hmac); // Convert the binary HMAC to a hex string

echo "HMAC: " . $hmac_hex;
?>
```

The code will produce output : `HMAC: 857ab7a94a4c103e3a8cc0442db0d4745064bb73`

Live test : https://3v4l.org/q4rJj

Comment: thanks figures out it will also work like this

       $t=hash_hmac('sha1', pack("H*", $macaddr), pack("H*", '8544e3b47eca58f9583043f8'));

cheers